# Can we get the source code of Berkeley sockets API..

Tags: sockets

I mean the source code of sendto, recv, listen... I mean how they internally work at the kernel level...?

Comment: Please reward the people who have helped you in the past first and accept more answers to your older questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can get the kernel source code for the sockets API, simply download any of the open source UNIX or UNIX-like kernels: [Linux](http://www.kernel.org), [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/) ([Building and Installing a Custom Kernel](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html)), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/) ([Building the System from Source](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html)), [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org) ([NetBSD Documentation: Kernel](http://netbsd.org/docs/kernel/)) and probably others.

Comment: Sorry, that would take me too much time. But I can tell you that in all of these kernels, the implementation of the Berkeley sockets are spread over several files. Understanding these implementations is a very heavy task. If all you want to do is gain an understanding on how to *use* the API, you better grab a book like Marc J. Rochkind's [Advanded Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/). If you want to reimplement it, maybe start by reading the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html).